# Citing inside theorem header

Tags: bibliographies, citing, theorems, optional-arguments

How do I create something like this without getting any errors?

```
\begin{thm}[\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}]
...
\end{thm}
```

I tried putting various things into {...} brackets, but not eliminating any errors. I probably have misunderstood something about how LaTeX works in the background and the AMS packet:

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Mask the content of `thm`' s optional argument with an additional set of braces.

EDIT: For what it's worth, with `ntheorem` loaded one needs *two* additional sets of braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[{{\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}}}]
A theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ABC2011} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I get these errors, when I do that:
Argument of \@citex has an extra }.

Runaway argument?

    page 10\color@endgroup 
Latex Error: Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
Latex Error: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

Comment: It must be some other package which is causing troubles :\

Comment: Tried it on a fresh file and it worked like a charm.. *bummer*.

Comment: @user46365: What packages that might affect theorems do you use (amsthm, ntheorem)? What document class? A working example would be even better.

Comment: @user46365: Strange enough, my example still works if I load `amsthm`, but not with `ntheorem`. Obviously you don't use `ntheorem` if it works for you now.

Comment: it worked when I opened up a new file and just copy pasting what you did above, but as you said it seems to be ntheorem which is causing the troubles.

Comment: I edited my question above to reflect this

Comment: @user46365: I edited my answer.

Comment: two brackets, who would have thought. thanks! have a great day.

Comment: @user46365: You're welcome! If you're allowed to do so as an unregistered user, please don't forget to also upvote my answer. ;-)

Comment: just registered so I could upvote it. :D

Comment: thanks. I had the same issue with the `pdfcomment` package and references to `includegraphics` and `SIunitx`. adding two extra sets of curly brackets solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[\protect{\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}}]
A theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ABC2011} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

regards

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be conflict between the packages ntheorem and amsthm. As a slightly different solution to Fiandrino's, I change

`[\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}]`
to `[{\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}}]`,

then it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}}]
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ABC2011} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have another solution. I don't use the package `theorem`.

I just change `[\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}]` to --> `{[\cite[page 10]{ABC2011}]}`.

Comment: Welcome! This answer has already been given by others, please make sure that your answer is really a "new answer" before clicking that button. Small improvements on existing answers can be suggested in the comments or with the "edit" button.