# Citations in theorem environment

Tags: citing, amsthm

In the body of my document, I am able to refer to do the following without any problems: 
`\cite[Lemma 2]{ABC}` renders as [ABC, Lemma 2] (with the appropriate hyperlink to the bibliography). However, LaTeX gets angry when I attempt 
`\begin{theorem}[\cite[Lemma 2]{ABC}] xyz \end{theorem}` and fails to compile; presumably it is using the first `]` to close the first `[` rather than the second. The desired output would look something like

**Theorem 1** ([ABC, Lemma 2])**.** xyz

(with the hyperlink to the bibliography preserved). Is there a way to make this compile properly? I am using amsthm, in case that is relevant. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: [Citing inside theorem header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17107)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `[]` inside `[]` which confuses the parser. Use `{}` to protect/hide the inner pair:

```
\begin{theorem}[{\cite[Lemma 2]{ABC}}]
```

Comment: That works great, thank you!