# Referencing a Specific Citation in a Theorem or Definition Statement

Tags: citing, definition

Let's say I want to write Definition 1.1 of a source I call \cite{fr82}. I can write `\cite[Definition 1.1]{fr82}` without any trouble, and I can write

```
\begin{defn}[\cite{fr82}]
blah blah
\end{defn}
```

without any trouble. However, when I write

```
\begin{defn}[\cite[Definition 1.1]{fr82}] blah blah
blah blah
\end{defn}
```

I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
Definition 1.1)
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.488 \begin{defn}[\cite[Definition 1.1]
                                        {fr82}]\label{defn:geom_fib}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best
```

Any idea for how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have tried encasing the contents of the optional argument in curly braces, i.e., writing `\begin{defn}[{\cite[Definition 1.1]{fr82}}]`?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Citing inside theorem header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17107)

Answer (score 1):

You need to encase the contents of the optional argument of the `defn` environment in curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[{\citealt[Definition 1.1]{sm82}}] 
Blah blah blah blah.
\end{defn}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Smith(1982)]{sm82} Smith, J., 1982, \dots
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!